# Unity TestRunner doesn't call Update() in edit mode test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, tdd, gameobject

I'm trying to learn how to unit test in unity and have run into a strange problem. I suspect I"m missing something pivotal in the early stages, but can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

I created a very simple MonoBehaviour:

```
public class SimpleMono : MonoBehaviour {

    public int frameCount = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        frameCount++;
    }
}
```

Now to try to test that this works I've written two tests. One tests that frameCount is zero the first frame, and the other tests that frameCount is 1 the 2nd frame. In the 2nd test, it yields return null, and then asserts. Since yield return null lets it go to the next frame. Therefore, one frame should have passed in which the update method got called.

```
public class NewTestScript
{

    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator frame0test() {
        SimpleMono simpleMono = new GameObject().AddComponent<SimpleMono>();
        simpleMono.frameCount = 0;

        Assert.AreEqual(0, simpleMono.frameCount);
        yield return null;
    }

    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator frame1test() {

        SimpleMono simpleMono = new GameObject().AddComponent<SimpleMono>();
        simpleMono.frameCount = 0;

        yield return null;

        Assert.AreEqual(1, simpleMono.frameCount);

    }
}
```

However, Test1 passes, yet test2 does not. Update is not getting called by either test. I tried putting a Debug.Log("FRAME FIRED") statement in the update method to check if it was called as well and it didn't do anything.

[image: test runner output]

I would have expected both tests to pass.

If in fact this is intended behaviour, where Update does not get called, what use are [UnityTest]s?

Comment: According to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlaymodeTestFramework.html when you're unit testing something in edit mode, that is when `yield return null;` will skip the current frame. Play mode seems to be the mode your tests will run in, so I think you need to use `yield return new Update();`. Let me know if that works!

Comment: I think you're right. But then what is the edit mode UnityTest for?